# keytool error: java.lang.Exception: The -keyalg must be specified

Tags: java

I am trying to create a key pair and storing them in a key store from the Windows command line prompt (using Windows 10 JDK 14). Here is the command I am typing:

```
keytool -genkey -alias chris -keystore chirskeystore
```

First, system prompts me for a password then re-enter the password and finally, it returns with the following error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: The -keyalg option must be specified.
```

The command is directly from the Oracle tutorial on java security:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolfilex/step2.html

Searching for the `-keyalg` or the error led to nowhere. Any insight will be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you have an older version of keytool? I can't find an easy way to query for its version...

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. The keytool in my JDK\bin has a date stamp of 5/4/202 with size 20 KB. May I ask if yours is more recent?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well it turned out that keytool in the JRE\bin is more recent 6/6/2020 than the one in the JDK\bin 5/4/2020. The keytool in the JRE\bin works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I get the exact same error with Adoptium Temurin Java version 17.0.3 with command:

```bash
keytool -genkeypair -alias chris -keystore chirskeystore \
    -storepass "MyPassword123" -dname "CN=MY_FQDN"
```

The fix for me is to be explicit about `-keyalg` value:

```bash
keytool -genkeypair -alias chris -keystore chirskeystore \
    -storepass "MyPassword123" -dname "CN=MY_FQDN" \
    -keyalg dsa
```

Note `-genkey` from initial question is an alias for `-genkeypair`.

And option `-keyalg` had before default value `dsa` for `-genkey`. But now it's required to specify it. Oracle should update their tutorial on java security.

One more thing: the latest documentation of `-keyalg` can be find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/keytool.html) on oracle.com